# create user using casl for role based permission

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, node-modules, casl

I am trying to use casl-mongoose for role based authentication

role.js

```
    module.exports = function (user) {
      const ability = defineAbility((can) => {
        switch (user) {
          case "admin":
            can(["create", "read", "update", "delete"], "User");
            break;
          case "user":
            can("read", "User", { role: "user" });
            break;
               }
           });

     return ability;
     };
```

user.js

```
const defineAbilitiesForUser = require("../middleware/roles");

user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password", "role"]));
const ability = defineAbilitiesForUser(req.user.userRole);
// req.ability.throwUnlessCan("create", user);
ForbiddenError.from(ability).throwUnlessCan("create", user);
```

I got ForbiddenError even I used role correctly.I want to know how to use "create" in casl.

```
ForbiddenError: Cannot execute "create" on "User"
    at Function.i.from (/home/madhu/Madhu/JavaScript/codedigital/casl_final/node_modules/@casl/ability/dist/umd/index.js:1:7009)
    at /home/madhu/Madhu/JavaScript/codedigital/casl_final/routes/users.js:52:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

json object

```
req.user : admin

{
    "name": "aaa",
    "email": "aaa@email.com",
    "password": "password",
    "role": "user"
    
}
```

Comment: It's unclear where `req.user.userRole` is the property that holds role name or `req.user.role`. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your code and if you pass `"user"` instead of `req.user.userRole`, you won't be able to create a user because your permissions says that user with role "user" can only read users with role "user".

If you pass `"admin"`, then everything is ok and error is not thrown.

The link to repl - https://repl.it/@stalniy/so-63132256

Comment: @madhu-yadav Can you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: case "countryAdmin":
        can(["read"], "User", { role: "countryAdmin" });
        can(["create", "read", "update", "delete"], "User", {
          role: ["regionAdmin", "stateAdmin", "cityAdmin"],
        });
        break;

Comment: Please check with this condition.

Comment: There are five roles[superAdmin, countryAdmin, regionAdmin , stateAdmin, cityAdmin ]

Comment: Please read this page - https://casl.js.org/v4/en/guide/conditions-in-depth#match-one-of-few-items-in-a-scalar-property to understand how to define conditions